# Boostrap menu mobile Jumping when open

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having an issue with my boostrap everytime in mobile i try to open the collapsed menu its shows a little "jump". Already tried to style the class .in but still nothing. Any hint what might be happening?

You can see the issue  in http://real-embrace-portugal.pt/

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is your main.css same as bootstrap.css?

Comment: The boostrap.css is inside my main.css with import rule (i am using LESS)

Comment: Did you add any custom css?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by the carousel of images.

You need to stop the carousel when scrolling

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    //User is scrolling
   //Stop the carousel
   $('#myCarousel').carousel('pause');
});
```

you can use

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel('cycle');
```

for start the carouse cycle again

Answer (score 0):

please use this css.. i think ur problem is solve..

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #777;
  height: auto !important;
}
.collapse.in {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}
}
```